# Show that a topology consisting of two points and the empty set does not arise from a metric on the two points

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

> Consider a two-point set $M = \{a, b\}$ whose topology consists of the
>   two sets, $M$ and the empty set. Why does this topology not arise from
>   a metric on $M$?

I'm not sure what this question is asking me to do? Am I to show that $M$ is not metrizable?

I am sorry if I am not providing an attempt at an answer, I'm just completely lost here.

Comment: Yes, I think you should prove that $M$ is not metrizable.

Comment: Suppose you put a metric on $M$. What will your open sets look like?

Comment: There wouldn't be any open sets? I cant think of how they could exist with a finite set of points like this

Answer (score 1):

Assume $d$ is a metric on the set $M = \{a, b\}$ where $a \neq b$ and let $\delta = d(a, b)$. Then $\delta \neq 0$ because otherwise $a = b$. The set $U = \{x \in M \mid d(x, a) < \delta\}$ is then open by definition of the topology on a metric space. But $U = \{a\}$ is not open in the topology described in the question (the indiscrete topology). By an extension of this argument (taking $\delta = \min\{d(x, y) \mid x, y \in M, x\neq y\}$)  you can show that a finite metric space has the discrete topology: the topology in which every subset is open.

Comment: I am not too familiar with indiscrete topology so I'm not sure how we can know that the described topology is indiscrete. Is it because the only open sets are M and the empty set?

Comment: That is the definition of the indiscrete topology. You don't need to know that bit of terminology to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Any topology arising from a metric is Hausdorff. But with $\{\emptyset,M\} $ you cannot separate  $a $ and $b $.

Comment: We havent learned about Hausdorff spaces yet, just metric spaces, is there a similar solution that doesn't depend on Hausdorff? Thanks